# residue fields of smooth $\mathbf{Q}$-algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, fields

Let $A$ be a $\mathbf{Q}$-algebra. We say $A$ is "residually abelian", if there exists a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$ whose residue field $\kappa(\mathfrak{m})$ is a Kummer extension of an abelian extension of $\mathbf{Q}$.

(In particular, trivial Kummer extensions of abelian extensions, ie. abelian extensions, are allowed).

**Question.** If $A$ is, in addition, a smooth $\mathbf{Q}$-algebra, does there exist a $\mathbf{Q}$-algebra map $f : A\to B$, with $B$ residually abelian, and such that either of the following conditions holds?

(a) $f$ is finite étale.

(b) $f$ is a Zariski localization.

(c) $f$ is finite.

(d) $f$ is faithfully flat, finitely presented.

(e) $f$ is either of the above, and $B$ is, in addition, a smooth $\mathbf{Q}$-algebra.

**Rem. 1.** By the Nullstellensatz, if $A$ is smooth then the condition "Kummer extension of abelian extension" is really "finite Kummer of finite abelian".

**Rem. 2.** It seems possible to obtain (e) from (c) and (d) by resolution of singularities, while it would be obvious from (a) and (b).

**Rem. 3.** As pointed out below, if $A$ is an arbitrary smooth $\mathbf{Q}$-algebra then $f$ will typically not allowed to be the identity.

Comment: Every finite field extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a smooth $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra.  If you choose $K/\mathbb{Q}$ to have non-solvable Galois group, e.g., the splitting fields of the polynomials of Schur, then none of (1), (2), or (3) can hold.

Comment: I edited the question a little.

Comment: I imagine what you're trying to show, whatever it is, is some property that spreads out in families with smooth base, and somehow you know how to check it when your object (scheme?) is defined over such a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Perhaps if whatever it is you're trying to show satisfies $h$-descent, a more useful question may be whether, for a smooth $\mathbb{Q}$-scheme $S$, there exists a proper surjection $S'\to S$ such that, for some finite extension $k$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ that is Kummer over abelian, $S'(k)\neq \varnothing$.

Comment: I don't see why this should be true, but your (a) and (b) are false. I'll write up an answer later.

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about intended applications.

Comment: If the answer were affirmative with nonzero $B$ then ${\rm{Spec}}(A)$ would have a rational point over a solvable extension of $\mathbf{Q}$, but for geometrically connected smooth affine curves over a number field it is an open question (I think generally expected to have a negative answer) whether such curves admit a "solvable point".  Hence, giving an affirmative answer that includes all geometrically connected affine curves would affirmatively answer a very difficult open problem (that moreover is I think generally expected to have a negative answer).

Comment: @Merlin. I can show smthg over $\mathbf{Q}$. Maybe I know how to reduce my conjecture from finite abelian extensions of $\mathbf{Q}$ to $\mathbf{Q}$... This was why